# Not able to click on button in java selenium?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng

HTML code:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-main dropdown-toggle" dropdown-toggle="" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">create
                <span class="icon-dir-down"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
            </button>
```

Using class name I tried to click on button but am not able to click.

I tried the following code:

```
driver.findElement(By.className("btn btn-main dropdown-toggle")).click();
```

Comment: Are there other `Web Elements` in your project that you are finding via `className`?  And, are they working?

Comment: @Brian No..help me please i don't know how to do it ...please

Comment: selenium contributor here. check out [this issue](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/1480) filed on our repository.  you are misusing `className`.  @PeterRasmussen's answer is the best way to accomplish it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try and get it by `cssSelector` instead. As far as I remember by `className` is only for one class.

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".btn.btn-main.dropdown-toggle")).click();
```

Comment: OP, Peter beat me to it.  I was going to suggest finding it by the `cssSelector` as well.  Give it a shot.

Comment: see my comment above.  @raghavendrat if you wanted to know why.. myself and luke (contributors to selenium) discuss the reasons

Comment: @Brian yes sure... I should wait 3 minutes to accept this answer

Answer (score 1):

Executing a click via webdriver has sometime unexpected behaviors.If its not working then alternate way `JavascriptExecutor` class to do this.
Its always preferable to use `click()` method of the `WebElement`.

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".btn.btn-main.dropdown-toggle"));
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```