# Find and click() function for a button

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

For the below inspects, I'm not able to click the button "MARK WEBATTENDANCE"

```html
<div class="box1child" ng-show="markAttendance"><button ng-show="showMarkAttendance"  style="background-color:#398439;">MARK ATTENDANCE</button></div>
```

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Ie()


driver.get("https:*********/WebAttendance/index.html")

mark_webattendance = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@ng-show='showMarkAttendance']")
mark_webattendance.click()
```

Comment: You shouldn't be locating it by internal AngularJS attributes; why not use `contains(text(), 'MARK ATTENDANCE')`?

Comment: Error: raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message: Cannot click on element

Comment: contains(text(), 'MARK ATTENDANCE') can you giva an example

Comment: That *is* the example, it's an XPath function

Comment: mark_webattendance = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//contains(text(), 'MARK ATTENDANCE')")
mark_webattendance.click() getting below error: selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: The xpath expression '//contains(text(), 'MARK ATTENDANCE')' cannot be evaluated or does notresult in a WebElement

Answer (score 1):

**Ways to Access button -**

```
var element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@id ='kk' and text()='MARK ATTENDANCE']");
driver.implicitly_wait(10000);
element.click();
```

**OR**

```
var element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[text()='MARK ATTENDANCE']");
driver.implicitly_wait(10000);
element.click();
```

**OR**

```
var element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[contains(text(), 'MARK ATTENDANCE')]");
driver.implicitly_wait(10000);
element.click();
```

Answer (score 0):

The xpath usage would be `//tagName[@attribute = 'value']` this is for exact match
`//tagName[contains(text(), 'value')]` this is for string that contains value
Another options is `//tagName[contains(@attribute, 'value')]`

Comment: mark_webattendance = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[contains(text(), 'MARK ATTENDANCE')]")
------------------------------------------
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message: Cannot click on element

Comment: The error message says element is not visible at the time of click. Could be a timing issue. For debug purpose try to put a wait (NOT GOOD PRACTICE) before performing click action

Comment: SAME ERROR:
driver.implicitly_wait(10000) 
mark_webattendance =driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[contains(text(), 'MARK ATTENDANCE')]")

Comment: Using implicit wait too is not good practice either.Try using Thread.sleep(5000). Also in some cases Selenium's click doesn't work in that case we use JavascriptExecutor. <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35161256/not-able-to-click-on-button-in-java-selenium>.

Answer (score 0):

mark_webattendance =driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[contains(text(), 'MARK ATTENDANCE')]")
driver.implicitly_wait(10000)
mark_webattendance.click()