# unable to locate element with anchor tag having onclick

Tags: java, selenium

unable to click on element which is under anchor tag and having onclick code to it.Need to click submit button.

I have provided implicit wait, and used xpath , css selector.

```
<a onclick="if(validateSupplierANDLocation(4)){return saveorsubmitorder(4);}else{return false;};" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lnkSubmit" tabindex="35" href="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$lnkSubmit&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;saveNexgenOrder&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, true))"><img src="../images/tspacer.gif" alt="" width="10" height="1"><img id="imgOSubmit" border="none" src="../images/buttons/submit.gif" alt="Submit" title="Submit" style="cursor:pointer    "><img id="imgOReSubmit" border="none" src="../images/buttons/btn_re-submit.gif" alt="Submit" title="Submit" style="cursor: pointer; display: none;"></a>

<img src="../images/tspacer.gif" alt="" width="10" height="1">
<img id="imgOSubmit" border="none" src="../images/buttons/submit.gif" alt="Submit" title="Submit" style="cursor:pointer    ">
<img id="imgOReSubmit" border="none" src="../images/buttons/btn_re-submit.gif" alt="Submit" title="Submit" style="cursor: pointer; display: none;">
```

> error: unknown error: Element  is not clickable at point (885, 911). Other element

would receive the click:

```
code: WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
        WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//html[1]/body[1]/form[1]/div[4]/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr[3]/td[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/a[1]/img[2]")));
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//html[1]/body[1]/form[1]/div[4]/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr[3]/td[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/a[1]/img[2]")).click();
```

Comment: Try the same code after removing /img[2] from xpath.

Answer (score 0):

The absolute path used to locate the button is not reliable as the location of the button could change within the DOM. Try to use a relative xpath. 
Try to debug to the point where you store the element in a WebElement variable. If this is your intended element then perform the click() action. 
`WebElement var = driver.findElement(By....)`

In some cases if the click action is not working then one has to use the JavascriptExecutor. Refer to the link [Not able to click on button in java selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35161256/not-able-to-click-on-button-in-java-selenium)